property status on null. Actually, the relationship from PengajuanKomponenItem to PengajuanKomponen is already a belongsTo
Let me share my code , i use laravel 11 and laravel excel for export record
this my export code
class PengajuanKomponenItemExport implements FromQuery , WithMapping , ShouldQueue , WithHeadings , ShouldAutoSize , WithEvents
{
    use Exportable;

    public function query()
    {
        return PengajuanKomponenItem::query();
    }
    public function map($PengajuanKomponenItem) : array
    {
        return [
            $PengajuanKomponenItem->bahanKomponen->nama,
            $PengajuanKomponenItem->jumlah,
            $PengajuanKomponenItem->bahanKomponen->satuan,
            Date::dateTimeToExcel($PengajuanKomponenItem->created_at),
            $PengajuanKomponenItem->pengajuanBahanKomponen->status,
            $PengajuanKomponenItem->bahanKomponen->harga,
            $PengajuanKomponenItem->jumlah * $PengajuanKomponenItem->bahanKomponen->harga,
        ];
    }
}

and this class PengajuanKomponenItem
class PengajuanKomponenItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'pengajuan_bahan_komponen_id',
        'bahan_komponen_id',
        'jumlah',
    ];

    public function pengajuanBahanKomponen()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(PengajuanKomponen::class);
    }
}

this class PengajuanKomponen
class PengajuanKomponen extends ApprovableModel implements HasMedia
{
    use HasFactory, InteractsWithMedia;

    protected $fillable = [
        // 'approved',
        'status',
        'keterangan'
    ];

    public static function status(): array
    {
        return [
            'Menunggu persetujuan' => 'Menunggu persetujuan',
            'Pembelian' => 'Pembelian',
            'Selesai' => 'Selesai',
        ];
    }
}

and i sure in my table have a records

i tried to get field status from PengajuanKomponenItem but when has access from any table that have a relation (pengajuanBahanKomponen) "a property have null value"
